# Returning <Case Class>.type with Case Class

Tags: scala

Given a case class:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
defined class Foo
```

I can define a method that returns `Either[Foo.type, ...]`.

```
scala> def f: Either[Foo.type, Int] = Left(Foo)
f: Either[Foo.type,Int]
```

When I tried to de-construct `Foo`, I saw a compile-time error:

```
scala> f match { case Left(Foo(a, b)) => a }
<console>:14: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Foo
 required: Foo.type
       f match { case Left(Foo(a, b)) => a }
```

But the following worked:

```
scala> f match { case Left(foo) => foo }
<console>:14: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Right(_)
       f match { case Left(foo) => foo }
res1: Foo.type = Foo
```

Given a `case class`, when is it appropriate to use a `<CASE CLASS>.type` type?

Comment: Probably almost never? `Foo.type` is the type of the companion object.

Comment: Probably you wanted `Either[Foo, Int]` instead of `Either[Foo.type, Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to deconstruct `Foo(a,b)` then you need to store a `Foo` and not `Foo.type`. The statement you have:

`def f: Either[Foo.type, Int] = Left(Foo)`

Is basically referencing the companion Object every time, and not an instance of your case class. You probably want something like:

`def f: Either[Foo, Int] = Left(Foo(1,"foo"))`

Comment: Kudos to m-z and Jesper for the comments, but I'd rather post an answer so the question can be closed. More useful for people looking around to help...